# XML validation of response message using SoapUI

Tags: xml, soap, xsd, soapui

I am trying to validate 2 responses which basically get generated from a request. Those 2 responses go into a message queue which will be consumed by the destination application. 
I want to ensure that the response messages are validated even before being consumed by the destination application. 
I only have soapui tool and I have XSDs of the destination response messages. Is there a way to validate those two responses generated just on the basis of the response xsds without any knowledge of the technical details like wsdl or whatever of the destination application.

Comment: Of course there are a myriad of ways to validate a response XML message given the XSD to which it must conform.   When you say, "*I only have soapui tool*," however, the possibilities are drastically reduced.  I've added the soapui tag to try to attract the right attention to your question.  Title updated as well.

Comment: I can't seem to understand what you are trying to accomplish. You want to validate the xml by using soapui (like saying manually) or programmatically when they are generated (automatically)?

Comment: SoapUI supports JMS: http://www.soapui.org/jms/getting-started.html although not well. If you want more help, have a careful read through [ask] and follow the instructions.

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/tips---tricks.html#5-1-Validate-request-XML-against-the-WSDL

Comment: Thank You for your responses. I achieved this by installing Eclipse and using the validate option with an xsd.